# "multiple definitions" error appears for char* arrays but not for unsigned char arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I am refactoring a c++ code and there is something I cannot understand. The code is declaring a set of arrays in a header file then include that header file in source files when needed. All arrays are "const unsigned char[]" except one which is "const char *[]" array. The latter is surrounded with an #ifdef SOMETHING. If SOMETHING is not defined code is built successfully, otherwise I got linker errors of multiple definitions for this "char *[]" only.

As a fix, I can eliminate those linker errors by adding "static" to "const char* XX[3] = {"X", "Y", "Z"}". This will keep the definition specific to the translation unit.

However, what I cannot understand why "multiple definitions" errors only occur with "const char* []" array and not with the others "const unsigned char[]" despite they are not preceded by a "static" keyword? Could someone explain that to me please?

Comment: Don't *define* the arrays in the header files, only *declare* them. For example, `const char* XX[3] = {"X", "Y", "Z"};` is a *definition*.

Comment: Yes Joachim, I know it is better to do as you said, but my question here is different it is about linker errors why gotten only for char*[] and not for unsigned char[]

Comment: The crucial difference lies in the `const`, not the `*` or the `unsigned`. `const unsigned char[]` is a const array, `const char*[]` is a non-const array (of const pointers).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Constant variables at namespace scope implicitly have internal linkage (if you will, they are implicitly `static`). The following declares and defines two distinct objects.

```
// A.cpp               // B.cpp

const T foo = 1;       const T foo = 2;
```

If you wanted *external* linkage, you'd have to say `extern const T foo;`.

By contrast, non-constant variables at namespace scope have external linkage (if you will, they're implicitly declared `extern`) and all denote the same object, so you are violating the one-definition rule:

```
// A.cpp               // B.cpp

U bar = 1;             U bar = 2;      // ODR violation
```

Here, if you wanted *internal* linkage, you'd have to say `static U bar;`.

This is your case. You have `T = char []` and `U = const char * []`. (Here `const T` produces the type `const char []` by 8.3.4/1.)

---

The solution is to not define your variables in headers if the variables have external linkage, since the header gets included in multiple translation units. Instead, only *declare* the variable in the header and define it in one single translation unit:

**library.h:**

```
extern U bar;            // in your case, extern const char * XX[];
```

**library_impl.cpp:**

```
#include "library.h"

U bar = 3;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, why you consider "const char* []" as "non-constant" at namespace. I still cannot understand this point. Could you clarify it please.

Comment: @Aymen: Because it is non-constant. What makes you think it's constant? (Hint: Please make sure you understand the C++ type declaration syntax.)

Comment: @Aymen: "At namespace scope" is C++'s way of saying "global variable". It's just that "global" isn't quite precise, because C++ has namespaces, but it's essentially that.

Comment: @Aymen: You can't just take random stuff out of context. Your type is `U = V *`, which is not the same as `const U = V * const`. The fact that `V = const char` is irrelevant. You have a pointer, and the pointer is mutable. It's true that the pointer points to something immutable, but that's irrelevant for the pointer itself. You're confusing `const char *` with `char * const`.

Comment: Thank you. You are too fast :)

Comment: @Aymen: OK, great - I hope it's clearer now! It takes some time getting used to pointers and indirection, but it's a vital step on the way to becoming a programmer :-)

Comment: It is ok now, thank you very much. You are too fast at typing, I didn't see your last comment before I post my own. Thank you, you deserve the best answer :). Oh yes! I will do my best to learn c++ better ;)